# How to open and close Android activity from cross-platform page in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have cross-platform app, but one function in my app can work only in Android (GooglePay). I created an activity for it, and trying to open this activity in Xamarin Form page using  DependencyService:

```
IPay pay = DependencyService.Get<IPay>();
Console.WriteLine(pay.GetResult());
```

Code of my activity is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65937861/xamarin-google-pay-implementation/66025190#66025190)

So, as I understand, I need to call it with Bundle object, because I got an exception in this code:

```
PaymentsClient paymentsClient = WalletClass.GetPaymentsClient(
             this,
             new WalletClass.WalletOptions.Builder()
                     .SetEnvironment(WalletConstants.EnvironmentTest)
                     .Build()
        );
```

As I understand, activity is null without a bundle. Exception is:

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException. Message = Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

So, I cannot find, if it is the right way to open an activity, and, if it is right, how to create right Bundle.

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally, I found the way to solve this problem.

Used [this](https://github.com/SPTutorial/GooglePaySample) sourse - not funcional, works only with GPay India, but have some good points:

- Use MessagingCenter to send data to native code and get it back
- Use MainActivity, because it is only activity, that can work with
  'null' Bundle

So now my code:

```
long orderId = 1;
long sum = 1;
long[] data = new long[2] {orderId, sum };

MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "PayViaGooglePay", data);

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>((App)Application.Current, $"tokenteleportation{orderId}", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
// getting result from arg
}
```

And code in MainActivity:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, long[]>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "PayViaGooglePay", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            OrderId = arg[0];
            PayViaGooglePay(this, arg[1]);
        });

//sending request, getting token

MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, $"tokenteleportation{OrderId}", TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google provides the SupportWalletFragment class, which will display a branded Purchase button within the fragment:

```
var walletFragment = SupportWalletFragment.NewInstance (WalletFragmentOptions.NewBuilder ()
    .SetEnvironment (WalletConstants.EnvironmentSandbox)
    .SetMode (WalletFragmentMode.BuyButton)
    .SetTheme (WalletConstants.ThemeLight)
    .SetFragmentStyle (new WalletFragmentStyle ()
        .SetBuyButtonText (BuyButtonText.BuyWithGoogle)
        .SetBuyButtonAppearance (BuyButtonAppearance.Classic)
        .SetBuyButtonWidth (Dimension.MatchParent))
    .Build ());
```

The `MaskedWalletRequest` class is used to build a new purchase request. You could use any payment gateway that can accept EMVCO Network Tokens, or in this case set up your Stripe account as the payment gateway with some configuration options:

```
var maskedWalletRequest = MaskedWalletRequest.NewBuilder ()

// Request credit card tokenization with Stripe
.SetPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters (
    PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.NewBuilder ()
        .SetPaymentMethodTokenizationType (PaymentMethodTokenizationType.PaymentGateway)
        .AddParameter ("gateway", "stripe")
        .AddParameter ("stripe:publishableKey", STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY)
        .AddParameter ("stripe:version", "1.15.1")
        .Build ())
    .SetShippingAddressRequired (true)
    .SetMerchantName ("Xamarin")
    .SetPhoneNumberRequired (true)
    .SetShippingAddressRequired (true)
    .SetEstimatedTotalPrice ("20.00")
    .SetCurrencyCode ("USD")
    .Build();
```

For more details you could check the [devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/bring-android-pay-to-your-apps-with-stripe/) .

You could also use the plugin [InAppBillingPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin) from Nuget . And get started by reading through the [In-App Billing Plugin documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/).

Comment: The problem is that I can not use Stripe, because it is not supported in my country, as well as gateways with EMVCO Network Tokens.